# Magento 2 translate placeholder text

Tags: magento2.2

How I can translate placeholder text Enter your password * ? I need edit this code?

```
<div class="form-group control-icon password required">
    <i class="icon fa fa-key"></i>
    <input name="login[password]" placeholder="<?php echo __('Enter your password *'); ?>" type="password" <?php if ($block->isAutocompleteDisabled()) :?> autocomplete="off"<?php endif; ?> class="input-text form-control" id="pass" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Password') ?>" data-validate="{required:true}">
</div>
```

Comment: read article - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html

Comment: I am checked magento 2 website guides. I tried to solve the problem but doesn't work. I do not have any idea.

Comment: can you please explain in detail? what are you trying to do? from that article howmany steps did you follow? where you got stuck ?

Comment: I tried two things. I added csv file text "Enter your password *","second language". I tried change placeholder="<?php echo __('Enter your password *'); ?>" to data-bind="attr: {placeholder: $t(''Enter your password *')}" />

Comment: where did you add you .CSV file? Location? Did you run `static:content:deploy` command?

Comment: CSV file location /app/i18n/mageplaza/de_DE and i run commands upgrade,deploy,reindex,flush.

Comment: I think that code is problem.

Comment: you CSV location is wrong. Check my answer

Comment: Have you tried inline translation - if it is only a few paragraph you would like to edit it should do the job.

Comment: Please remove the "*" from the text and check again because "*" is creating problem in translation

Comment: Solved this problem removing the character (*). So the translation works now! <?php echo __('Enter your password'); ?>

Comment: Please remove the * from the text and check again because * is creating problem in translation this is my comment where * is not showing in my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

Add you CSv file with Translation in Below location.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/i18n/de_DE.csv

```
"Your Text","Translation"
```

Comment: Doesn't work. mageplaza install guide is #### Step 1: Unzip and upload

Unzip the compressed file and upload file `de_DE.zip` into `app/i18n/mageplaza/de_DE/de_DE.csv`

Comment: @Peter, this doesn't appear to be a correct path.  In your Magento admin, what is your currently selected theme for the store you're on?